# Laravel show id

Tags: laravel

I want to get an id from `table 1` and take it to show something from `table 2`.
so it is difficult to explain.

I'll try to show it.

so each `$job` has a `firma`, the `firma` field is a number (like 1 ,2, 3).

if I do this:

```php
{{ $job->firma }}
```

it shows me a number.

Also, each user has `avatar`:

```php
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/' . $user[2]->avatar) }}">
```

if I do this, it shows me the `avatar` of the user with the `id=2`

now, I want to show the avatar of the user with the number of the `firma`.

Something like this:

```php
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/' . $user[job->firma]->avatar) }}">
```

but when I do that, it tells me this:

> Undefined offset: 4

And I don't know why :D

because if I split it everything works, but if I do this nothing works :(

Comment: Whats is ur $user array ? Also include here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined offset error happens when you try to access an element in an array that doesn't exist.

Instead of inserting the values 1, 2, 3, and 4 into `$user` you need to insert 0, 1, 2, and 3 by subtracting one from each.